# Smooth-scrollbar события сдвига?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день использую такой плагин
[smooth-scrollbar](https://github.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar)
Как получить эвент что когда страница листается выполнить функцию. Посмотрел все методы из документации но нигде нету события move или тому подобной

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следуя документации:

```
scrollbar.addListener()
```

и как результат:

```js
const scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('#inner-scrollbar'));

scrollbar.addListener((status) => {
  console.log('scrolling')
})
```

```css
#inner-scrollbar {
 max-width: 800px;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section id="inner-scrollbar" data-scrollbar>
 <img src="https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/images/your_diary.jpg">
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/smooth-scrollbar/8.5.2/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
```

Но стоит также помнить о предупреждении этого использования:

> Notice: the callback functions will be invoked **in every small
>   scrolling**, so be careful not to add time-consuming listeners which
>   will slow down scrolling.